# Table <name> has no column <column name>

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Estoy realizando un proyecto en Android y creando una b.d SQLite y en la clase que extiende `SQLiteOpenHelper` en el momento de hacer una inserción estoy obteniendo lo siguiente:

> table paradas has no column lng

Pero la tabla tiene la columna. Por errores de sintaxis en la variable donde esta el query para crear la tabla me faltaron 2 comas en los 2 últimos campos (lat y lng)

Para el primero ya lo resolví con el mismo método con el que he estado tratando de resolver el segundo: borrando datos de la app en el móvil, desinstalando la app del móvil e incrementando el número de versión de b.d pero en estos momentos no esta resultando. No se qué mas deba hacer para tabla quede con los campos en el momento de depurar o correr la app.

Por si acaso dejo las variables de cómo esta la sentencia que crea la tabla:

```
// Table Names
private static final String TABLA_PARADAS = "paradas";

// Columnas tabla paradas
private static final String PARADAS_CODIGO = "cod";
private static final String PARADAS_LAT = "lat";
private static final String PARADAS_LNG = "lng";

// Columnas comunes
private static final String ID = "_id";
private static final String NOMBRE = "nombre";
private static final String DESC = "desc";

// Table Create Statements
// Create statement tabla paradas
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PARADAS = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLA_PARADAS + " (" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + PARADAS_CODIGO + " TEXT,"
        + NOMBRE + " TEXT, " + DESC + " TEXT, " + PARADAS_LAT
        + " DOUBLE, " + PARADAS_LNG + "DOUBLE)";
```

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque es un error tipográfico.

Comment: @Nestor ahora tu pregunta es otra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes un error aquí:

```
 + " DOUBLE, " + PARADAS_LNG + "DOUBLE)";
```

esto es similar a:

```
 + " DOUBLE, lngDOUBLE)";
```

por esa razón tu query es incorrecto y cuando creas la tabla no existe el campo "`lng`", debes agregar un espacio:

```
 + " DOUBLE, " + PARADAS_LNG + " DOUBLE)";
```

Una opción para provocar se vuelva a generar la applicación por medio del método onCreate() de  SQLiteOpenHelper es limpiar los datos de tu aplicación:

[image]

- Otra opción es que al aumentar el numero de versión se  debe ejecutar onUpgrade(), solo asegura tenga un DROP de la tabla para que pueda generar nuevamente la estructura de la tabla.